# BigCommerce Add Active Menu Class

Tags: javascript, css, bigcommerce

I'd like to add a CSS class for the bigcommerce left side category list when that category is active. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no matter what you have tried, you can thy this code below hope it will work.

```
function extractPageName(hrefString)
{
    var arr = hrefString.split('/');
    return  (arr.length<2) ? hrefString : arr[arr.length-2].toLowerCase() + arr[arr.length-1].toLowerCase();               
}

function setActiveMenu(arr, crtPage)
{
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(extractPageName(arr[i].href) == crtPage)
        {
            if (arr[i].parentNode.tagName != "DIV")
            {
                arr[i].className = "current";
                arr[i].parentNode.className = "current";
            }
        }
    }
}

function setPage()
{
    hrefString = document.location.href ? document.location.href : document.location;

    if (document.getElementById("nav")!=null)
        setActiveMenu(document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("a"), extractPageName(hrefString));
}
```

Dont forget to add **nav** ID for menu div.